# Google Interview Question: Assign People and Cars optimally on 2D array

Tags: algorithm, array-algorithms

My friend recently got this question from google interview and I think this is a tricky question.

> Given People and Cars on 2D array, find an Optimal Assignment of
>   people and cars where you define what "optimal" means.

1. If we define Optimal Assignment as the least total Manhattan distance between all pairs (min sum of each pair's distance). What could be a good way to solve this and which algorithm should I use?
2. Is there any better way to solve this problem more efficiently with different definition of "optimal"?

Comment: As worded, there's not a particular correct answer.  If it's an interview question, they're probably interested in how ***you*** formulate and tackle the problem.  Given both of these things, it's not a good match for SO.  I would recommend browsing the [help section about asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) if you haven't already done so.

Comment: Can you also provide an example input and output ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use total manhattan distance (or total pretty much anything else), then this is an instance of the "assignment problem", or "minimum cost bipartite matching".

You can solve it using the Hungarian algorithm or other methods:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Answer (score -1):

I believe another condition is that for any person, the distances to any two cars should not be the same. And similarly for any car, the distance to any two people should not be the same. And ultimately you want to give everyone a car.

A greedy solution works like this: compute the distance of every (car, person) distances and sort them. Travel thru the array and pair the (car, person) if neither is paired. The algorithm takes O(mnlog(mn)) for m cars and n people but can be improved with 1. use parallelization when calculating distances 2. keep only a O(n) priority queue for each person. When a person is paired. We no longer add its distances to the queue. Hence the algorithm takes about O(mnlog(n)). The optimality can be proved by induction.

Comment: "The optimality can be proved by induction."  Are you claiming that greedy algorithms are provably always optimal?

Comment: In this setting the greedy solution is optimal. But for some other problems (e.g. traveling salesman problem) greedy solution is suboptimal. It really depends on the problem.

Comment: Sounds like an assignment problem to me, for which greedy algorithms are sub-optimal.  What's the basis of your claim that it's optimal?

Comment: First assume the algorithm works correctly for n inputs, then add another car and another person (that should be paired last), then compares distances (it's a bit convoluted but it's a good practice). You then will find that if the the the new car and person are not paired, the total distance will go up.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/72593/is-there-a-greedy-algorithm-to-solve-the-assignment-problem

Comment: well that seems to be a different problem and a different algorithm.

Comment: `When a person is paired. We no longer add its distances to the queue.` I don't understand that part. In the beginning we push all pairs of (car, person) to priority queue. And then we make pairs by extracting elements from priority queue. This is `O(nmlog(nm))`. Can you explain improvement 2)?  Is this means that you use multiple priority queues for each person separately instead of one global?